# Texture flips when sphere is UV-unwrapping

Tags: texturing, uv

When I make a UV-unwrapping for sphere, the texture is inverted (as in the image on the right):
[image]

I need continuous stripes (as in the image on the left). How to achieve this?

Note: I selected two cutting edges in the central ring.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any good way to do this unwrap with seams, your stripes will hardly join and they will be distorted. You should try another mode like for example *Sphere Projection* (or *Follow Active Quads*). Make sure that your sphere has a very small pole face, and that you're in front view when you'll do the unwrap. Then it should give something like that:

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much for your advice! This solved my problem!